# npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/.npm'

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to deploy a NodeJS server to Jenkins. But it's giving me the following error

[image]

Here's my Pipeline.yaml configuration

[image]

Any help on this will be appreciated

Comment: Seems Jenkins starts the `node:10.16.3-slim` with a user which not exists in container, thus the  user `HOME` directory is change to `/`,  but  the user not `root` or in `root` group, he can't create directory under '/'.   In such case you can specify the `HOME` directory via `HOME` environment

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the home directory to the environment in pipeline.yaml

```
environment:
   HOME: .
```